# Java: Trying to get the value of an HTML element

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, if-statement, automation

I am trying to extract the value of an HTML table element from a website and compare it to a user input value but it seems that the nested loop is not being entered when I run the program. It works with no errors but I am not getting any output from Eclipse, I'm new to Selenium Java and still learning.

See my code below:

```
String inputString = basePrem;
try {

    //Print to console the value of Base Prem
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[text()='Base Premium']/following-sibling::*"));
    List<WebElement> allrows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    List<WebElement> allcols = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));    

    for (WebElement row: allrows) {
        List<WebElement> Cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            for (WebElement Cell:Cells) {
                if (Cell.getText().contains(basePrem)) {
                    System.out.print("Base Premium = "+ basePrem + "   ");
                }
                else if (!Cell.getText().contains(basePrem))
                {
                    System.out.print("Base Premium = " + basePrem + " ");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
catch (Exception e) {
    errorMessage = "Value discrepancy";
    System.out.println(errorMessage + " - " + e.getMessage());
    driver.close();
}
```

Also, *inputString* is where I input the value I use for comparison (I use a separate excel file for testing)

Since the control is not going inside the nested loop, I probably have some logical error?

Comment: Can you print the allrows.size() and allcols.size() value and share the result.
Code: System.out.print("No of Rows "+ allrows.size());System.out.print("No of Rows "+ allcols.size());

Comment: It may not enter either of your `for` loops at all.

Comment: @notyou - that's what I am also guessing since it doesn't give me any output at all..

Comment: @Subburaj - tried this and not getting any output

Comment: Ensure that your XPath expression returns what you expect (the table) - test using e.g. https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. Then use a debugger to step through.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the code as below and then validate whether your inputstring is available in the table. It is not necessary to use nested for loops

**Code:**

```
    String inputString = basePrem;

    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table"));
    //Extract all the Cell Data Element
    List<WebElement> dataElementList=table.findElements(By.xpath(".//td"));

    for(WebElement dataElement : dataElementList){

        if(dataElement.getText().contains(inputString)){
            System.out.print("Base Premium = "+ basePrem + "   ");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: will definitely try this.